# Github API get user code merged into master branch of specific repo

Tags: rest, github, github-api

Just had a question regarding GitHub's REST api, I am looking through the documentation but cant seem to find what I am looking for. Is there a way to look up how much code a user has merged into the master branch over a period of time of a specific repo?

essentially I would like to get a return of

user `x` committed `x` lines of code in the range of `May 2020` to `May 2021`. Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GITHUB API**

Unfortunately, the Github API doesn't provide those informations (yet?), you'll only get the amount of contributions the user made to the repository with the [List repository contributors](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repository-contributors) service.

**WORKAROUND**

There seems to be a workaround:

Consulting this URL: `https://github.com/<repo_owner>/<repo_name>/graphs/contributors`, I observed the following requisition was made to fill contributors datas:

- Request URL: `https://github.com/<repo_owner>/<repo_name>/graphs/contributors-data`
- Request Method: `GET`
- Request Headers: *Not Sure...*

This endpoint will return something similar to the following object:

```
[
  {
     "total":N,
     "author":{
        "id":<user_id>,
        "login":"<user_name>",
        "avatar":"<user_avatar>",
        "path":"/<user_name>",
        "hovercard_url":"/users/<user_name>/hovercard"
     },
     "weeks":[
        {
           "w":1586044800,
           "a":0,
           "d":0,
           "c":0
        },
        {
           "w":1586649600,
           "a":0,
           "d":0,
           "c":0
        },
        ...
     ]
   }
 ]
```

On this response, you'll have a *list of contributors* with `contributors' details`, where:

- `total`: represent the amount of contribution this user made to the repository.
- `author`: the Github user datas.
- `weeks`: a list of weekly contribution where for each week:

  - `w`: is the week id
  - `a`: the amount of lines added
  - `d`: the amount of lines deleted
  - `c`: the amount of commits made

Therefore, to get what you want, you'll have to sum all weeks contributions for each user.

***Observation**: I understand that to do so, you need to have access to the repository insights (they may not be available to any user).*